# I can't use Imgur, I have to use Scratch instead

Tags: discussion, tags

Instead of Imgur mazes, I have to create Scratch mazes because
I can't access Imgur.

However, can I still use [imgur-maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imgur-maze) in it or may I
suggest another tag?

EDIT: I tried:
[image: Sorry, this image has been eaten by an evil kumquat.]

Comment: Because we want everything to be contained within this site, only Imgur should be used for this type of puzzle. (also there is a difference between [tag:imgur-maze] and [tag:mazes]). Uploading to Imgur is done automatically when you upload an image in puzzling so there should be no problem

Comment: That's the key question: when you upload an image to a post on Stack Exchange, does it still appear as an `i.stack.imgur` file like it does for people who can access Imgur? (I think so, but want to confirm before posting an answer.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor the website might be too slow for me.

Comment: @Adam I haven't tried using it right now, maybe I could try it later.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Nearly all images on this site gave me a ripped piece of paper followed by "enter image description here".

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I mean when *you* upload an image into *your* post, does it actually work? (Can you try uploading one into this meta post to check?)

Comment: Oh that sounds like a broken image link. Try clearing your browser cache (images and files). For more info please visit https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Randal'Thor I can't see the picture.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat But for us who can access Imgur, it looks fine. So you would be able to make a puzzle which works just fine for most site users, except that you yourself wouldn't be able to see it properly :-)

Comment: Just FYI, imgur is actually *mutely* banned in Indonesia.. making it even impossible to enjoy most of the puzzles..